# heroku not wanting to play nice with my p5-react app

Tags: reactjs, heroku, p5.js

im trying to use p5.js with react but my issue is that it works locally but when i push to heroku i get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

here's the code of the sketch:

```
import React from "react";
import Sketch from "react-p5";
 
export default () => {
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    let spacing = 10;
 
    const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
        // use parent to render the canvas in this ref
        // (without that p5 will render the canvas outside of your component)
        p5.createCanvas(500, 500).parent(canvasParentRef);
        p5.background(0);
        
    };
 
    const draw = (p5) => {
        // NOTE: Do not use setState in the draw function or in functions that are executed
        // in the draw function...
        // please use normal variables or class properties for these purposes
        p5.stroke(255);
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) { 
            p5.line(x, y, x + spacing, y + spacing);
        } else { 
            p5.line(x, y + spacing, x + spacing, y); 
        }

        x = x + spacing;
        if (x > p5.width) {
            x = 0;
            y = y + spacing;
        }
    };
 
    return <Sketch className="C64Sketch" setup={setup} draw={draw} />;
};
```

and the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//import { appendScript, removeScript } from './ModScripts';

import Navbar from './Navbar';
import C64PRINT from './sketches/10PRINT';


class C64_10p extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='c64 component_container'>
                <Navbar />

                <div className="my_spill c64">
                     this is the famous C64 one line program.  this vertion takes more then one line though.
                </div>

                <div className="10_print sketch_container">
                    <C64PRINT />
                    <a href='https://shawkai91.github.io/p5js-fafs/10PRINT/' target='_blank'>
                        here is a link to it because heroku was not liking how i was doing it
                    </a>
                    <div className="sketch_container-discription"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default C64_10p;
```

and a link if needed: https://shawkai-test-app.herokuapp.com/

Comment: im using react-p5 npm in this case

Comment: Weird... I don't even see you using `"Super"` anywhere. Have you tried this with a functional component?

Comment: is that different then what i did???

Comment: This line: `class C64_10p extends Component` means that you're making a class component.

Comment: how does that change things?

Answer (score 0):

got it to work by using "react-p5-wrapper" instead of "react-p5"